# Import new JAR file from another project every time to address new change

Tags: java, maven

I am locally working with 2 projects one for service layer and another for Entity layer. When any change is made in Entity layer I would like to have that change in Service layer.

What would be the best way to manage JAR file from Entity layer in Service layer so that I can have every change from Entity layer for development.

I tried adding lib folder in Service layer to handle Entity JAR file and made following change in POM

```html
 <dependency>
      <groupId>projectName</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/Entity-1.0SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But could not load files from JAR file.

Is there any better solutions for this?

Comment: Create a multi module build ....

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so you can just import both projects, if the service one depends on the entity one, just add the dependency without the scope and systemPath. The IDE should resolve it to you. Just make sure that the version of the entity matches the dependency entry